# Information other than WSDL using JAX-WS for SOAP?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, soap, jax-ws

I am using JAX-WS to export some SOAP Web Service Endpoints.

I know I can access the WSDL by appending ?WSDL to the web service endpoint.  (Like http://localhost:8888/web_service/test?WSDL

Is there any other information I can get by appending things to the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a look at the generated WSDL (if you're using @WebService annotation) you can see that you can find the XSD with "?xsd=1".

I don't know how standard this is, though, and if there are cases where you could have different values than 1.